# How to create Auto suggestion text box in vb.net windows application?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create an auto suggestion textbox in vb.net windows form where the data in the dropdown should come from a particular column in the sql database table.

Can anyone suggest how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set `AutoComxxxxxx` properties of *TextBox*.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `AutoComplete`. Below is an example of `ComboBox` but `TextBox` has also the same property names on it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**[More on this link (complete details)](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/mahesh/auto-complete-textbox-in-vb-net/)**

Comment: I want the values in the dropdown to appear from a database table and I am not getting it from your example..

Comment: you need to set the `AutoComplete = CustomSource` and Set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource = <collectionFromDatabase>`

Comment: But in the AutoCompleteCustomSource, we need to enter the items manually..so do you mean that I should enter all the values of the column from the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim months As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
data.Add("January");
data.Add("February");
data.Add("March");
data.Add("April");
data.Add("May");
data.Add("June");
data.Add("July");
data.Add("August");
data.Add("Septeber");
data.Add("October");
data.Add("November");
data.Add("Decmber")

'Then Set ComboBox AutoComplete properties
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = months
```